# How to Enable Drag and Drop for anroid mobile application in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin to develop an android mobile application and I try to use Drag and Drop in view/registration form to make design as I think if I use it I can make design faster but I can not able to use drag and drop in direct UI I can drag from toolbox and drag in in Xaml file but not direct?
Anybody have any solution.. please help me

Comment: In fact, I think it's just a helper function, you couldn't rely on it to drag and drop to the exact location you want,you still have to set it in your XML.